# Feature Detection Opencv

Tags: c++, opencv, image-processing

I am a beginner in OpenCV feature detection and matching. I  am trying to write one simple method to detect and display the detected feature with an image.Here is the method that I have written:

```
void FeatureDetection::detectSimpleFeature(Mat image){
    Mat gray_image, output_image;
    cvtColor(image,gray_image,CV_BGR2GRAY);
    // Detect Keypoints using Simple Detector
    Ptr<Feature2D> detectors;
    vector<KeyPoint> keypoint_1;
    detectors->detect(image, keypoint_1);
    drawKeypoints(gray_image, keypoint_1, output_image, Scalar::all(-1), DrawMatchesFlags:: DEFAULT);
    namedWindow("Keypoints Detection");
    imshow("Keypoints Detection", output_image);
    waitKey(0);
}
```

There is no compile time error in this function, but while running, the program is crashing.Can anyone please help?

I am also searching special types of detector like SURF, SIFT etc but could not find in my downloaded and built library. Please suggest !!!

Comment: Have you look at the OpenCV [tutorial](http://docs.opencv.org/3.2.0/db/d70/tutorial_akaze_matching.html)?

Comment: Hi Catree, I tried changing my method based on this example.

Comment: I am using AKAZE detector, I want to use SIFT/ SURF detector but could not find these detectors in the installed library. What could be the possible reason?

Comment: SIFT / SURF are in [OpenCV contrib module](https://github.com/opencv/opencv_contrib).

Comment: you will find them available on OpenCV 2.4 version

Comment: While building contrib i am getting this error in testdetection class

Comment: In function 'cv::String {anonymous}::findDataFile(const cv::String&)':
 error: 'findDataFile' is not a member of 'cvtest'
test_detection.cpp:15:19: note:   '{anonymous}::findDataFile'
C:\opencv\opencv\sources\modules\contrib\modules\text\test\test_detection.cpp:15:19: note:   '{anonymous}::findDataFile'

Comment: error: 'findDataFile' is not a member of 'cvtest'